# How to insert named slots into parent components

Tags: vue.js

Named slots are very useful in overriding sections of a component, like so:

```
<warning> <template slot="text">Custom warning text!</template> </warning>
```

How does one use named slots to override sections of `warning` component within a parent component, one level up?

```
<component-with-a-warning>
    <template slot="text">Custom warning text!</template>
</component-with-a-warning>
```

I illustrated this problem better in a JS Fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/madhazelnut/pdzoeqj0/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to wrap a component inside another component and be able to optionally specify the slots of the inner component from slots defined on the outer component.

A `<slot>` can also be rendered inside the slot of another component by adding the `slot="name"` attribute to it, just like you would any other component that you want to render within a slot.

```js
Vue.component('warning', {
  template: '#warning',
});

Vue.component('wrapped-warning', {
  template: '#wrapped-warning',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```css
.warning {
  background-color: gold;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<template id="warning">
  <div class="warning">
    <h1><slot name="heading"></slot></h1>
    <div><slot name="text"></slot></div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="wrapped-warning">
  <warning>
    <slot name="heading" slot="heading">Default wrapped heading</slot>
    <slot name="text" slot="text">Default wrapped text</slot>
  </warning>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <wrapped-warning></wrapped-warning>
  <wrapped-warning>
    <template slot="heading">Overridden heading</template>
    <template slot="text">Overridden text</template>
  </wrapped-warning>
</div>
```

Comment: Since I asked the question I did some experimenting and managed to insert the slot from grandparent component to a child inside a middle component but I had to wrap the <slot>-s into a <template> first. I tried your approach without the template and it doesn't seem to produce results. Am I doing it wrong?